# SVG and Javascript not working 'online' in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, svg

I have been creating a map of a local town center and it has taken ages, I wanted it to be in **SVG** so I could zoom in and out and also have 'popup' details when the cursor moves over an element.  This is done in **Javascript** (I am a beginner!!).

I have searched here and online and cobbled together something good BUT it doesn't work if I put it into a 'window' as seen here

http://www.poipleshadow.com/Goa-Mapusa-Market.

(scrolling and zooming breaks and the text becomes tiny!)

I am hoping there is a Javascript/SVG god somewhere out there who can help

The same image works here on its own

http://www.poipleshadow.com/Images/Mapusa-Market.svg

Comment: Out of interest, did you use anything like http://raphaeljs.com/?

Comment: Yes I have seen raphaeljs although as I am a beginner at js I like to have small sections which I 'try' to understand.

Comment: Comes up with svgDocument not defined for me in Chrome, so maybe start there.

Comment: Thanks Ian, it didn't actually come up with that error for me, but I seem to have solved it for the first issue now - THANKS - Although there is still the issue of viewing it in the window and text/controls not behaving.

Comment: Use <iframe> or <object> instead of <img> if you want the svg to be interactive.

Comment: Erik - Well, that was much easier than I expected it to be - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Eric, The reason that the SVG behaved differently was because it was in an image tag

**DIDN'T WORK**

```
<img src="Images/Mapusa-Market.svg"  alt="Mapusa Market" width="900" height="300" />
```

**DOES WORK**

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="Images/Mapusa-Market.svg"></object>
```